# TypeScript Interface-Member prefixing

Tags: typescript, interface, naming-conventions

### Problem

According to my research, typescript interfaces exist only at compiletime and have no according structure in JS, whereas a class does.

That's why you cant explicitly implement interfaces, as you can do this in other languages like c# for instance.

consider this example:

```
export interface FooableBar {
    foo();
}

export class Bar implements FooableBar {
    foo(){}
}
```

Of course if i wanted to have another implementation of `foo()` for `Bar` I could simply rename it.

But what if `Bar` was to implement a second Interface like this:

```
export interface SpecialFooable {
    foo();
}
```

This is where explicit implementations would do the job perfectly. Unfortunately this has to be done with naming.

### Question

Generally asking: *What is the best way to do this in TypeScript?*

or *What sort of naming-convention does fit the TypeScript concepts the most?*

For instance, i've found that it is common to use a prefix for libraries or frameworks like angular. Where this interface may be found:

```
export interface OnInit {
    ngOnInit();
}
```

prefixing `ng` indeed provides the option to just implement `onInit()` our own, but in my case adding a `app` prefix would not solve the problem at all.

Comment: I don't see the problem. What's wrong with having your class implement one `foo()` method to satisfy two interfaces?

Comment: the whole point is, that sometimes you must. mostly solved by having implementations to depend on each other, just as you can do this when overriding a method and calling the base-method inside somewhere.

Comment: Sometimes you must what? You probably have something in mind, but it's not apparent from your question. It's unclear what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen im working around not being able to explicitly implement interfaces with naming. I wonder if that is the best practice to do so. Of course this is a question not related to functionalty. Its more a matter of writing clean code.

Comment: Maybe someone else will take a stab at answering your question, but I don't know what "not being able to explicitly implement interfaces with naming" means.

Comment: @rob in typescript you can't explicitly implement interfaces, as explained you can do this eg. in c#: `Interface.Method(){}` Because this syntax doesn't exist for reasons I explained in my question, i am working around this by naming.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the solution to prefix an abbrevation of the interface-name:

```
export interface SomeFancyDelegate {
    sfdLoadData();
}
```

But im still interrested in any other or hopefully better solution.

*Anyway, would you in this case alaway prefix your interface members for consistency?*